# Change object label on specific value in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, charts

I'm working on charts in React.js and i want to display data sorted by month. In django i've created view for displaying json with total events per month and it looks like this:

```
    [
        {
            "month": "2022-06-01T00:00:00+02:00",
            "total": 4
        },
        {
            "month": "2022-08-01T00:00:00+02:00",
            "total": 1
        }
    ]
]
```

I would like to sort every object in that array and change value 'month' from numbers to month name, so it would be:

```
    [
        {
            "month": "june",
            "total": 4
        },
        {
            "month": "august",
            "total": 1
        }
    ]
]
```

For generating charts i'm using chartist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the full date as a seperate key (called date), and set the month in a seperate function using a predefined array for the names of each month. Here is the code you would use:

```
const monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",     
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]; // Array representing each month

var chartItems = [
    {
        "date": "2022-06-01T00:00:00+02:00",
        "month": null,
        "total": 4
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-08-01T00:00:00+02:00",
        "month": null,
        "total": 1
    }
];

// Run through each item in the array
function setMonths(arr) {
    arr.forEach(item => {
        const date = new Date(item.date); // Convert date string to Date object
        const monthIndex = date.getMonth(); // Get index of month from the Date
        const month = monthName[monthIndex]; // Convert index into text representing the month

        item.month = month; // Set the month key in the object to the new month
    });
}

setMonths(chartItems); // Call function to set months in the array
```

As an alternative, you could also make a method for each object in the array that gets the month, but you would need to run this everytime you want to get the month. Here is the code for that:

```
const monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",     
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var chartItems = [
    {
        "date": "2022-06-01T00:00:00+02:00",
        "month": function() { return monthName[new Date(this.date).getMonth()]; },
        "total": 4
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-08-01T00:00:00+02:00",
        "month": function() { return monthName[new Date(this.date).getMonth()]; },
        "total": 1
    }
];
```

And you would get it like this:

```
chartItems[0].month(); // "[0]", meaning the first item in the array
```

Comment: Your first example works like charm, but only when chartItems are typed in code. Actually i'm getting these objects from api, and putting them to an array, and then nothing happens. Even so i'm copy pasting the very same object from console but one is hard typed and the other is pushed from axios

Comment: I get it working just by rearranging the code.

``` axios.get(":8000/").then((res) => {
    let months = res.data.month;
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      chartItems.push(months[i]);
      if (chartItems[i] === undefined) {
        chartItems.pop();
      }
      if (chartItems[i] !== undefined) {
        chartItems[i].month_name = null;
      }
    }
    ** HERE IS YOUR EXAMPLE**
  });```

Comment: If my solution helped, make sure to mark it as correct so other people know the solution. :)